# Matching regex href=javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regex that matches `href='javascript:...'` or `href="javascript:..."`, but I also want to match a `href=javascript:...` without quotes.

How can I do it?

My regex: `/\bhref\s*=[^"']*(?:"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')/gi`

Strings that I want to match:

```
<a href='javascript:alert(1)' sometags>click me</a>
<a href="javascript:alert(1)" sometags>click me</a>
<a href=javascript:alert(1) sometags>click me</a>
```

Sample of code:

```
while((match = reg.exec(s)) !== null) {
    // In each cases I want to get javascript:alert(1) in match
}
```

Comment: Make the quote optional with `"?`

Comment: ...or remove them `\bhref\s*=\S*`

Comment: Do you only want the matches to be in <a> tags? sounds silly to have `href` anywhere else, but just to clarify with your needs

Comment: Use the DOM to do it.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. This can be achieved with regex, but it's a bad application for it. This is what DOM is for.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another case to your alternative. If there's no quote, it matches until the next whitespace or `>`.

```
/\bhref\s*=\s*(?:"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'|([^\s>]*))/gi
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/KjjA0U/1)